# while using py-script in html I am facing some issues

Tags: html, streamlit, pyscript

while using py-script in html i got this error:-

[ERROR image you can check here by opening the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDHN7.png)
i watched youtube videos but can't find any solution, i need to solve this error as soon as possible, cause this is my final year college project

Comment: Have you tried pip installing streamlit? Without code it's hard to see what your problem would be elsewise.

Answer (score 1):

Streamlit is unlikely to work directly in PyScript - it relies on the assumption that it's running in a Desktop Environment in a number of ways.

You should have a look at [stlite](https://github.com/whitphx/stlite), which allows you to run Streamlit-style code client-side in the browser using Pyodide.